# Microsoft mvc 5 view not displayed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I develop a website for a company in asp.net MVC 5 with EF 6, JQuery and bootstrap.
In my controler I call a oracle- Db and collect some data from a view ( doesn't matter, I know).
this is my code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
   if (id == null)
   {
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
   }
   var v_PERSONEN = await db.V_PERSONEN.FindAsync(id);
   if (v_PERSONEN == null)
   {
    return HttpNotFound();
   }
   return View(v_PERSONEN);
 }
```

This Action is called from a different View and works fine. The View (v_PERSONEN) is called ( compiler stops at a breakpoint in the view).

But: The view can't be displayed. There is no error-message in Firebug.

this is the View:

```
@model DVZ.FAJ.FM.Ranglisten.Web.App_Data.PERSONEN

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>People</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PEPK)
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PENAME, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PENAME, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PENAME, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PEVORNAME, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PEVORNAME, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PEVORNAME, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Anyone any idea what causes that strange behavior?

Many thanks in advance!
P

Comment: Which name you give to View (v_PERSONEN)? where is it inside your project?

Comment: It is here: ~/Views/Personen/Edit.cshtml.
As I said, it stops at the breakpoint in the view.

Comment: `V_Personen` is not the same as `Personen`

Comment: what type is variable `v_PERSONEN`

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things that you may want to check :

**Ensure your Model Is The Correct Type**

Currently, your View is expecting a `DVZ.FAJ.FM.Ranglisten.Web.App_Data.PERSONEN` object to be passed into it. You'll want to ensure that this is the exact same type that is being returned from your call within your Controller :

```
// This should be using an PERSONEN object like your View is expecting
var v_PERSONEN = await db.V_PERSONEN.FindAsync(id);
```

**Check Your View Name**

By default, MVC will attempt to map a Controller Action to a View of the same name (e.g. `Index` will map to `Index.cshtml`). Your existing code doesn't appear to explicitly specify a View, so it will assume that is in the following location :

```
~/Views/YourControllerName/Edit.cshtml
```

If that isn't the name of the View, you'll want to specify it when calling the View :

```
return View("YourViewName",v_PERSONEN);
```

**Check Your Syntax in Your View**

You may want to consider checking through each of the helpers within your View and ensuring that they are being mapped to the expected properties of your Model and that the syntax for each of the helpers is correct.

**UPDATE**

It looks like there was a missing closing `</div>` tag that cooresponded to your existing `<div class='form-horizontal'>` tag that was causing your `BeginForm()` call to not find it's closing `}` brace :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>People</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PEPK)
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PENAME, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PENAME, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PENAME, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PEVORNAME, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PEVORNAME, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PEVORNAME, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- This was the culprit -->
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Wouldn't the breakpoint being hit if the view wouldn't be on the right path?

Comment: Assuming that the name of the Controller is `PersonenController`, then yes, it should hit the proper View. You may want to try removing sections of the View one at a time to see if you can isolate the issue. I know that syntax errors can pop up rather quickly when working with multiple `htmlAttributes` objects, so that could be an issue.

Comment: The name of the controler ist PersonenControler. I tried to isolate sections one by one. But that didn't show some other effects.

Comment: It looks like there is a missing `</div>` tag after your last `form-group` section. I've updated my response with an example of where it should be added.

Comment: That is caused by a copy-Paste mistake. The original view is many lines longer and the html- code is correct. 
I deleted almost every line in my view:

Comment: Could you post a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) of what the entire View looks like?

Comment: The Edit-Action is called from a Grid.MVC via Js. But I cannot see, that this will cause any errors. Am I right?

Comment: Not really. You could explicitly define that you are going to be loading a partial view if that is the case by using `return PartialView(v_PERSONEN);` instead of just `return View(v_PERSONEN);` but that shouldn't make a significant difference.Have you tried using the Developer Tools (F12) within your browser and monitoring the "Network" tab? It should allow you to see the Requests / Responses, which can sometimes provide a bit of information about the error.

Comment: yes shure: but now this view is empty :-). Just a few lines left.

Comment: I already tried to find any error with the dev-Tools. But couldn't find any.

Comment: Now the view is like that:
@model DVZ.FAJ.FM.Ranglisten.Web.App_Data.PERSONEN
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

But it is still not displayed.

Comment: If there are no errors present within the Developer Tools and your View simply isn't loading, I'm not really sure what to tell you. You might consider checking the Console in Javascript as it sounds like something is definitely going wrong. Try just putting a single static string in the View and removing the model to see if that even works. If not, then it's likely an issue with how the View is being called / loaded.

Comment: Strange thing: The answer in the networking tool is correct. But it is not rendered in Firefox. That sounds imposible. Can that be caused by the asynch Actions? I can't explain it. 
Many thanks for your help. If I find any solutions for that I will post it here.

Comment: If you can see your results in the Developer Tools, that means that your content is actually coming back. It's likely that you are making an AJAX call within your Grid and the results simply aren't being set within the DOM afterwards like the following example : `$.ajax('url',function(results){ $('#your-container').html(results);`.